# Get useful stats from IIS log files

Tags: iis, analytics

Does anyone know of a free tool that I can use to get website statistics from my IIS log files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Brief Description**
>
> Log parser is a
> powerful, versatile tool that provides
> universal query access to text-based
> data such as log files, XML files and
> CSV files, as well as key data sources
> on the Windows® operating system such
> as the Event Log, the Registry, the
> file system, and Active Directory®.

http://www.microsoft.com/DownLoads/details.aspx?FamilyID=890cd06b-abf8-4c25-91b2-f8d975cf8c07&displaylang=en

Comment: Thanks David. I should have been more clear... I needed to send a client a general report of their stats from their website logs. I managed to get it done with Analog (http://www.analog.cx/) which produced a single report.html, though it was quite basic and not too easy on the eyes!

Answer (score 2):

[awstats](http://awstats.sourceforge.net) is a free tool that can also be set up to handle IIS log files. It provides the info in a nice web-based interface.